# How to generalize the notion of hyperplane to matrices?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

In Boyd's textbook "Convex Optimization" there is an example:

[image]

In the above proof that PSD cone is convex, there is this claim that the set of the form $\{X \in \mathbf{S}^n| z^TXz \geq 0\}$ are "halfspaces in $\mathbf{S}^n$".

From my understanding reading from the same text, a hyperplane is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | a^Tx = b\}$, and a halfspace is when the set has $\geq$ or $\leq$. This definition **only works for set of vectors**.

Therefore, how is halfspace in $\mathbf{S}^n$ or a hyperplane in $\mathbf{S}^n$ defined? And do these concepts carry the same graphical intuition as in the vector case?

Comment: If $V$ is a real vector space, then a *hyperplane* in $V$ is a set of the form $\{v \in V \mid f(v) = b\}$ for some nonzero linear function $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$. Check this agrees with the hyperplane definition using $a^T x = b$. Likewise, a halfspace is a set of the form $\{v \in V \mid f(v) \geq b\}$. Note that we are only using $\geq$ in the set $\mathbb{R}$, not in $V$ itself. Now you just need to check that $S^n$ is a vector space, and for any fixed vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X \mapsto z^T X z$ is linear.

Comment: Another idea is to think of $\mathbf{S}^n$ as being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$. This follows by taking the upper triangular entries of $X \in \mathbf{S}^n$ (including the diagonal), and concatenating them in a vector. This mapping is bijective.